# Толкование слова адажио?

Tags: этимология

А́жио (итал. aggio от лат. agio «превышение») — финансовый термин, означающий прибавочную стоимость или излишек, который платят за  денежные знаки или ценные бумаги сверх их номинальной цены.

Ажиота́ж (от фр. agiotage) - горячка на биржах и рынках; внезапное появление повышенного интереса к чему-л., спроса на что-л., (перен.) - сильное возбуждение, борьба интересов вокруг какого-либо дела, вопроса.

Это так и есть или только кажется, что слова *адажио*, *ажиотаж* и  *ажио*  имеют общую основу со словом *живо*(й)? Уж очень схожи по смыслу и похоже звучат: *ажиотаж* с *оживать* и *ажио* с *нажива* (прирост, приплод, доход).

Можно ли слову *адажио* дать толкование, пусть менее изящное, но более понятное, чем приведено в википедии?

Answer (score 2):

адажио
[ит. adagio] (муз.). 1. нареч. Медленно, протяжно (о темпе исполнения музыкальных произведении). 2. нескл., ср. Музыкальная пьеса или часть ее, исполняемая в темпе адажио. Лунная соната Бетховена начинается певучим адажио.
Большой словарь иностранных слов.- Издательство «ИДДК», 2007.

Остальное вряд ли входит в компетенцию сайта (этимология итальянского слова, его состав), лучше обратиться непосредственно к итальянцам или специалистам по итальянскому языку.

https://italian.stackexchange.com